# Structs not working, getting garbage output

Tags: c, struct

Intuitively below should seemingly work, 1) define a structure; 2) attempt to load values; 3) print them.

This code creates an extra line break after the first but does not print out any of the values that user inputs.

```
#define NODES 5

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node* next;
}
node;

int main(void)
{
    node nodes[NODES];

    for (int i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
    {
        printf("Value of node %i: ", i);
        nodes[i].val = scanf("%i\n", &nodes[i].val); 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
    {
        printf("Value of node %i: is %i \n", i, nodes[i].val);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this line:

```
nodes[i].val = scanf("%i\n", &nodes[i].val);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%i\n", &nodes[i].val);
```

As per the man page, `scanf` returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned. So your code is reading in the right value, but assigning the return value of `scanf` to the member, thereby overwriting the value assigned earlier.

Reference: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html